# Having problems with "snoozing" alarm

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Does anyone know how to do snooze function and where I am going wrong?

My default snooze time is 5 minutes. It worked fine until restart the
application and then does not work again.
If I clear the cache and data its works again.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int iSnoozeLeft = settings.getInt(PuzzleAlarm.SNOOZE_LEFT, 1);
    if (iSnoozeLeft != 0) {
      Intent activate = new Intent(AlarmNotification.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmNotification.this, 0, activate, 0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

      int iMinutes = Preferences.getSnooze(settings, AlarmNotification.this);
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.roll(Calendar.MINUTE, iMinutes);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);

      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt(PuzzleAlarm.SNOOZE_LEFT, iSnoozeLeft - 1); // disabling
      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }`
```

Comment: Restructured the question to make it more readable. Improved the English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmNotification.this, **0**, activate, 0);

Make sure you aren't using "0" for your other alarm ID. In other case your "snooze" code will overwrite that previous alarm.

Comment: you are right but why it happened when i restart the application the same alarm which i created will not work after edit it and set the alarm time..it has the same id as it created first..

Comment: Another thing if i create second alarm or third alarm it work fine when application is launched first time but i got nothing after restarting the app...